# NHibernate 3.3.1 explicit polymorphism

Tags: nhibernate

I use NH 3.3.1.
Suppose simple classes:

```
public class TestBase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string A { get; set; }
}

public class Test : TestBase
{
    public virtual string B { get; set; }
}
```

and mappings for them:

```
public sealed class TestBaseMap : ClassMap<TestBase>
{
    public TestBaseMap()
    {
        this.Polymorphism.Explicit();
        this.Id(a => a.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        this.Map(a => a.A);
    }
}

public sealed class TestMap :SubclassMap<Test>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        this.Map(a => a.B);
    }
}
```

Even with Polymorphism.Explicit() specified, NH still left joins Test when querying for TestBase.

```
var a = this.Session.Get<TestBase>(1);
```

I don't really need this joining 'cuz will have lots of subclasses.
I checked xml generated by fluent. it's ok, "explicit" clause is there. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I wanted to read some data from a cache, or from an archive. The data type was the same in both cases, only the data source was changed. I did not find a possibility to change this data source at runtime, therefore I used a derived class. Since my mapping must use CompositeId, I couldn't inherit it from SubclassMap for the derived class. To avoid the problem with the unwanted join when reading the data, I used the setter: this.Polymorphism.Explicit() in both mapping classes. This solved the problem in the end.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that explicit polymorphism is only used in queries, not for session.Get. But I couldn't find any references for this.

---

Try to not query for the base class, but always have an concrete subclass (which is in most cases a better design anyway):

```
public abstract class TestBase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string A { get; set; }
}

public class TestA : TestBase
{
    public virtual string B { get; set; }
}

public class TestB : TestBase
{
    public virtual string B { get; set; }
}

var a = this.Session.Get<TestA>(1);
```

Comment: I've tried both queries and get. no luck. I'll try to use previous NH versions. People write this feature worked fine some time ago.

Comment: It may also be the problem that you query for the base class. You should try inheriting all concrete instances. I added another section to my answer.

Comment: Thank you Stefan for your answer. But in this case i'm forced to have one concrete base class. Because all these classes instances should share one Id sequence (i mean IDs should not repeat among of them). I try to implement authorization policy. There's a base table with identity id. And there's permission table which stores information about user groups accessing these records. In your case there're gonna be many not linked tables, and for all of them I should create its own permission table. Assuming that there'll be 40-50 subclasses, it's not good solution. Maybe you know good design?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I've got it. As Stefan supposed, i made abstract TestBase. But since I really needed to query TestBase table without many left joins, i introduced stub class:

```
public class TestStub : TestBase
{
    // nothing   
}
```

This class is absolutely empty. Map:

```
public sealed class TestStubMap : SubclassMap<TestStub>
{
    public TestStubMap()
    {
        this.Table("TestBase");
        this.KeyColumn("Id");
    }
}
```

Now I can query:

```
var a = this.Session.Get<TestStub>(1)
```

It produces only one join (TestBase join TestBase). So now i can get my TestBase from db without overhead. I don't like hacks, but if built-in logic doesn't work (polymorphism=explicit), what is left to do.